# Como herdar um formulário em VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, herança

Preciso herdar um formulário em um projeto no **VBA** para usá-lo como base para outros formulários.

Por exemplo, um formulário chamado "**Tabela**" contém uma lista de duas colunas e botões para '**Editar**', '**Incluir**' e '**Excluir**' os itens; e sempre que fizer uso de tabelas no projeto este formulário deverá servir como base, mas podendo fazer implementações em cada caso:

**TabelaEstado**: conterá a *Sigla* de cada estado e sua *Descrição*, usando como base o formulário **Tabela** sem alterações.

**TabelaTaxaDeEntrega**: conterá a *Sigla* do estado, sua respectiva *Descrição* (que deverá usar os dados da **TabelaEstado**, o que é uma implementação sobre o formulário **Tabela** original), o *Bairro* (uma descrição simples) e o *Valor* da taxa de entrega, usando também o formulário **Tabela** como base mas com duas novas colunas que deverão ser criadas além das duas existentes no original (total de quatro colunas para os dados).

A ideia é poder fazer alterações no formulário **Tabela** que seriam assumidas pelos formulários que se baseiam nele, por exemplo, incluindo um botão '**Ajuda**' que será comum a todos e assumido automaticamente, sem ter de incluir este botão formulário a formulário.

Tem como fazer?

Comment: Achei a sua pergunta muito interessante, mas não vou responder porque eu realmente não sei. Dei uma olhada rapidamente no meu Excel aqui (versão 2010) e não parece haver uma forma nativa de fazer o que vc quer (porque cada `userform` é independente e você nem tem acesso direto à classe dele). Também não parece ser possível simplesmente copiar e colar um formulário existente. Assim, uma ideia que eu avaliaria é escrever código para gerar novos formulários automaticamente a partir de um existente. Continua...

Comment: Assim, talvez seja possível você escrever um código que avalia um "formuláro-base" e cria uma cópia igual (um novo, pra vc manipular manualmente), e que também compara com outro formulário existente pra adicionar nele automaticamente apenas os componentes que não existirem (os novos componentes). Deve ser possível. Sugestão de leitura: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/204330

Comment: Luiz, obrigado pela dica. A sua pergunta que também é interessante eu sugiro que faça no site (como copiar e colar formulários), pois eu sei responder e acho que vai ser útil para muita gente.

Comment: Oi Leo. Você mesmo pode fazer a pergunta. Quando você faz uma pergunta, existe a possibilidade de marcar um checkbox e respondê-la você mesmo. :)

Comment: Luiz, tentei de várias formas executar os exemplos do link que indicou, mas em todos os casos deram erro. Por favor, você poderia gerar um exemplo? Se for o caso gero uma nova pergunta para isso, mas com este exemplo, creio que sirva como "resposta" por não ter outra forma de fazer.

Comment: "mas em todos os casos deram erro" -> Qual erro? Eu poderia, se tivesse tempo (ultimamente tá difícil). O ideal é você tentar fazer um [mcve] e abrir uma nova pergunta sobre o tal erro.

Comment: Ok, criei a questão: Como criar formulários dinamicamente em VBA?