# Erros na utilização do objeto Application.VBE dentro do VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Em apoio à solução da questão ["**Como herdar um formulário em VBA?**"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128636/73), executei as orientações e exemplos do site [support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/204330](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/204330) com a finalidade de gerar formulários dinamicamente.

O código abaixo refere-se a um formulário com dois botões que acionam as rotinas dos exemplos.

Nos **remarks** estão descritos os erros ocorridos, porém, por falta de maior experiência no **VBA** não consegui resolver os problemas.

Parecem estar relacionados à necessidade de adaptação de versão, mas também não sei como resolver neste caso, meu **Excel** é o **2016 (Microsof Office 365)**.

Há dois **remarks** no código que são de testes dos exemplos que executei e desativei após a ocorrência dos erros, basta tirar os **remarks** e executar para testar cada um.

Uma observação, a indicação de ativar a referência **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility** foi feita anteriormente aos testes, conforme orientação do site.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 VbeCompName

End Sub


Sub VbeCompName()

 'MsgBox ActiveDocument.VBProject.VBComponents.Count
 'Erro: O objeto é obrigatório

 'MsgBox Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Count
 'Erro: O acesso de programação ao projeto do Visual Basic não é confiável

 X = VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Count
 'Erro: O objeto é obrigatório

 For I = 1 To X

  MsgBox VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents(I).Name

 Next I

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

 BuildMyForm

End Sub


Sub BuildMyForm()

 Set mynewform = _
    VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Add(ComponentType:=vbext_ct_MSForm)
 'Erro: O objeto é obrigatório

 With mynewform
      .Properties("Height") = 246
      .Properties("Width") = 616
      .Name = "HelloWord"
      .Properties("Caption") = "This is a test"
 End With

End Sub
```

O que está errado ou faltando neste caso? Existe algum exemplo funcional similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu código tinha alguns problemas/erros:

1 - No Excel, o objeto não se chama `ActiveDocument`, e sim `ActiveWorkbook`. Isso está escrito na documentação (só faltou prestar um pouquinho de atenção ;) ):

> (In Microsoft Excel, replace ActiveDocument with ActiveWorkbook; in
>   Microsoft PowerPoint, substitute ActivePresentation.)

2 - A documentação é geral pra todas as ferramentas do Office, mas no Excel o objeto `VBE` é uma propriedade do objeto `Application`. Então você sempre precisa usar `Application.VBE...`.

Dessa forma, o código que funciona fica assim:

```
Sub VbeCompName()

 MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Count

 MsgBox Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Count

 X = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Count

 For I = 1 To X

  MsgBox Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents(I).Name

 Next I

End Sub
```

Além disso, há outra questão importante. O acesso ao projeto via código é potencialmente perigoso, pois pode ser utilizado por vírus pra danificar arquivos. Por isso, **o usuário** (sim, somente ele) precisa autorizar esse acesso (caso contrário você obtém o erro da segunda linha). Essa autorização precisa ser configurada no Excel. [Nesta minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113795/73) tem o passo-a-passo.

Comment: Muito bom, funcionou, obrigado pela atenção de sempre!

Comment: Por nada. :) Boa sorte.